# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with Total Derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $y:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ also be differentiable. I'm interested in applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to the function $f(y(\cdot),\cdot)$, which itself is a differentiable mapping from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $f_1$ denote the partial of $f$ with respect to the first coordinate and $f_2$ denote the partial of $f$ with respect to the second coordinate. Then is it true that
$$f(y(b),b)-f(y(a),a) = \int_a^b y'(x)f_1(y(x),x) + f_2(y(x),x)\ \mathrm{d}x$$
where the integrand is the total derivative of the function $f(y(\cdot),\cdot)$ with respect to $x$. On the other hand, let's fix some $\bar x\in \mathbb{R}$, then is it true that
$$f(y(\bar x),b)-f(y(\bar x),a) = \int_a^b f_2(y(\bar x),x) \ \mathrm{d}x.$$
I can't seem to find these results proved rigorously, so any references would be great.

Comment: Aren't those direct consequences of the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: And you need one more tool, the regular multivariable chain rule.